# Having trouble returning element ID with onclick event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am just getting started on learning to code and am trying to create a game of checkers with what I have learned. After learning to back up my original attempt the hard way, I have restarted and am applying what I have learned since my original attempt by creating my board and checker pieces dynamically with JS.

The problem I am running into this time around is when it comes to adding `eventListeners` to my checkers. I have successfully gotten them to function as buttons and can get the assigned function to run when i click the button (although it runs every time I run the code as well), but I want to have the button return it's own ID when clicked so that I can use it in the functions that will move the checker pieces. I'm probably in a little over my head as I've only been learning for a couple of weeks but I don't want to give up on the dynamically created pieces just yet. Any help is appreciated.  Here are my functions that I've written (any advice is welcome):`

```
 function addElement(parent, newTag, newId, html, newClass){
 var p = document.getElementById(parent);
 var newElement = document.createElement(newTag);
 newElement.setAttribute('id', newId);
 newElement.innerHTML = html
 newElement.setAttribute('class', newClass)
 p.appendChild(newElement);

 }



function addOnclick(checkerId, func){
  var checker = document.getElementById(checkerId);
   checker.onclick = func;
    checker.addEventListener("onClick", func);
  } 


function returnId(id){
   console.log(id);
}'''
```

This is where I attach the event to each piece:

```
for( i = 10; i<90; i++){

   if (i % 10 === 0 || i % 10 === 9){addElement("board", "div", "s"+i, "X", "dummySquare")
} //select non "dummy" squares//


  else{
      var button = 0;
      var x = "s"+i;
    addElement("board", "div", "s"+i, "", "square" );
    if(startingPosition.indexOf(x)>-1){
      if (i<50){
      addElement("s"+i, "button", "b"+i, "x", "checker")
      document.getElementById("b"+i).classList.add("redChecker")
       };
        if (i>50){
      addElement("s"+i, "button", "b"+i, "x", "checker")
      document.getElementById("b"+i).classList.add("blackChecker")
       };
      // starting checkers added//
      addOnclick("b"+i, returnId)
```

*EDIT*
After getting the `onclick` event to work, I am wanting to return the id property of the button in question: my thoughts were to try to call target the id property directly, then return it (log it just to make sure that it is functional first) but my approach  is not doing the trick.  It seems that the id argument is null and I'm not sure why.

```
function returnId(id){
   element = document.getElementById(id);
   elementId = element.id;
   console.log(elementId)

}
```

Comment: You need to pass the function `returnId` not call it. `addOnClick("b" + i, returnId);`

Comment: Thanks that linked to event to the function returnId, upon doing so I realized that it is returning the entire element with all of its properties. I'm trying to get it to only return the id property of the element. My thought process is that I need to do something like

Comment: "document.getElementById(id).id" and then return the result to the function but I seem to be missing something. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Event handlers actually receive an event object containing the relevant information. So you can use `function returnId(event) { console.log(event.target.id);}` you should not call it returnId though because it does not return anything you and that makes the name confusing

Comment: I see, I'll update the function name now. I plugged that in and it worked beautifully. Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this 5-6 hours and could not make sense of it. To make sense of it when a button with a listener is clicked, said button becomes the argument of the function that is attached. Making it an object that you can work with? Man I can't thank you enough for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help.